# How to create a .csv file from the results of an array?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, csv

I'm using a PHP class to Check the email validity in real-time,
The PHP Script works fine: Check the emails and print the results in the same page creating a `<td>` element for each validated email.

My problem is I'm trying to validate around 200,000 emails... the result of the script is a huge list causing my browser to stop working.

Is it possible to create a .csv file with the results instead of just print them on the page? If so, how can I do this?

Here is my source code:

index.php <-- this is the file that shows the results.
emailvalid.php <-- This is the PHP Class

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 8]> <html lang="en" class="ie8"> <![endif]-->  
<!--[if IE 9]> <html lang="en" class="ie9"> <![endif]-->  
<!--[if !IE]><!--> <html lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->  
<head>
    <title>EmailValid</title>
    <!-- Meta -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">    
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">  
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,300italic,400italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'> 
    <!-- Global CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Plugins CSS -->    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/plugins/prism/prism.css">
    <!-- Theme CSS -->  
    <link id="theme-style" rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/styles.css">
    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head> 

<body data-spy="scroll">
    
    <!---//Facebook button code-->
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>(function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.0";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
    
    <!-- ******PROMO****** -->
    <section id="promo" class="promo section offset-header">
        <div class="container text-center">
            <h2 class="title">Email<span class="highlight">Valid</span></h2>
            <p class="intro">Check the email validity in real-time
   <form method="post">
    <textarea rows="10" cols="150" style="color:black" name="email" placeholder="Insert here your text. The robot will extract all the emails from the text"></textarea>
    </p>
    <div class="btns">
     <input type="submit" value="Check" name="Check" class="btn btn-cta-secondary">
    </div>
   </form>
   <?php include 'assets/emailvalid.php'; ?>
            <ul class="meta list-inline">
            </ul><!--//meta-->
        </div><!--//container-->
    </section><!--//promo-->
     
    <!-- Javascript -->          
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/plugins/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/plugins/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/plugins/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>   
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>     
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/plugins/jquery-scrollTo/jquery.scrollTo.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/plugins/prism/prism.js"></script>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/main.js"></script>       
</body>
</html>
```

```html
<?php
$show_details     ='yes';    // choice : 'yes' or 'no'
$disposable_email    ='yes';  // choice : 'yes' or 'no'
$check_mx      ='yes';  // choice : 'yes' or 'no'

     
if(!empty($_POST['Check'])){
 if(!empty($_POST['email'])){
 
  $emails = get_email($_POST['email']);
  require_once('emailvalidclass.php'); //include emailvalidclass.php file
  $emailChecker = new emailChecker; // Make a new instance
  if($show_details=='yes'){ $emailChecker->supress_output = 0; }else{ $emailChecker->supress_output = 1; }
  if($disposable_email=='yes'){ $emailChecker->filter_dea = 1; }else{ $emailChecker->filter_dea = 0; }
  if($check_mx=='yes'){ $emailChecker->check_mx = 1; }else{ $emailChecker->check_mx = 0; }
  $emailChecker->smtp_test = 0; 

  $emailsubmited=count($emails); 
       
  echo '<br><b>Emails : </b>'.$emailsubmited;
       
       echo '<hr><table cellpadding="10" cellspacing="10" border="1" style="margin-top: 15px;">
         <tr style="font-size:20px;background-color:black;color:white">
          <td>Email</td>
          <td>Passed</td>';
       if($show_details=='yes'){ 
          echo '<td style="text-align:left">Email valid ?</td>';
          if($disposable_email=='yes'){ 
           echo '<td>Disposable ?</td>';
           }  
          if($check_mx=='yes'){
           echo '<td>Domain MX Check ?</td>';
           }  
       }  
        echo ' </tr>';
       $array_good_emails=array();
       $array_bad_emails=array();
       $array_good_no_duplicate_emails=array();    
       
       foreach((array)$emails as $key=>$e){
       
        if(empty($e)) continue;
       
        $e = $emailChecker->check($e);
        $e = $e['result'];
        // echo '<pre>';
        // print_r($e);
        // echo '</pre>';
        if($e['success']){
         $array_good_emails[]=htmlspecialchars($e['query']);
        }else{
         $array_bad_emails[]=htmlspecialchars($e['query']); 
        }
       ?>
      <tr>
       <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($e['query']); ?></td>
       
       <?php if($e['success']){
          echo '<td style="background-color:green">yes</td>';    
         }else{
          echo '<td style="background-color:red">no</td>';    
         }
       ?>
       
       
       <td>
       <?php if(!empty($e['report']['validate_email'])){ 
          echo 'yes';    
         }elseif(!empty($e['errors']['validate_email'])){
          echo 'no';    
         }
       ?>
       </td>
<?php if($show_details=='yes'){ ?>
 <?php if($disposable_email=='yes'){ ?>  
      <td> 
        <?php if(!empty($e['report']['filter_dea'])){ 
           echo 'no';
          }elseif(!empty($e['errors']['filter_dea'])){
           echo 'yes';
          }else{
           echo '-';
          }
        ?> 
      </td>
 <?php } ?>
 <?php if($check_mx=='yes'){  ?>
        <?php if(!empty($e['report']['check_mx'])){ 
           echo '<td>yes</td>';
          }elseif(!empty($e['errors']['check_mx'])){
           echo '<td>no</td>';
          }else{
           echo '<td>-</td>';
          }
        ?>
 <?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
      </tr>

      <?php
       }
       echo '</table><br><br>';
       
      ?>
 <div class="panel panel-default">
                                    <div class="panel-heading">
                                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                                            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">Show Passed/Good Emails</a>
                                        </h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse in" style="height: auto;">
                                        <div class="panel-body" style="color:black">
                                            <?php echo implode("<br>",$array_good_emails); ?>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>    
 <div class="panel panel-default">
                                    <div class="panel-heading">
                                        <h6 class="panel-title">
                                            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" class="collapsed">Show Bad Emails</a>
                                        </h6>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse" style="height: 0px;">
                                        <div class="panel-body" style="color:black">
                                            <?php echo implode("<br>",$array_bad_emails); ?>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
                                    <div class="panel-heading">
                                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                                            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseFour" class="collapsed">Show Passed/Good Emails (without duplicate emails) </a>
                                        </h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="collapseFour" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                                        <div class="panel-body" style="color:black">
                                            <?php $array_good_no_duplicate_emails=array_unique($array_good_emails); 
            echo implode("<br>",$array_good_no_duplicate_emails); ?>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>    
      
      
  
      <?php

  

 }else{
  echo 'Email field empty. Please, try again';
 } 
}


function get_email($text) {
      ## Regex taken from http://bit.ly/Tq2PYP PHP's FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL function.
      $email_pattern = "/(?!(?:(?:\\x22?\\x5C[\\x00-\\x7E]\\x22?)|(?:\\x22?[^\\x5C\\x22]\\x22?)){255,})(?!(?:(?:\\x22?\\x5C[\\x00-\\x7E]\\x22?)|(?:\\x22?[^\\x5C\\x22]\\x22?)){65,}@)(?:(?:[\\x21\\x23-\\x27\\x2A\\x2B\\x2D\\x2F-\\x39\\x3D\\x3F\\x5E-\\x7E]+)|(?:\\x22(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0B\\x0C\\x0E-\\x1F\\x21\\x23-\\x5B\\x5D-\\x7F]|(?:\\x5C[\\x00-\\x7F]))*\\x22))(?:\\.(?:(?:[\\x21\\x23-\\x27\\x2A\\x2B\\x2D\\x2F-\\x39\\x3D\\x3F\\x5E-\\x7E]+)|(?:\\x22(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0B\\x0C\\x0E-\\x1F\\x21\\x23-\\x5B\\x5D-\\x7F]|(?:\\x5C[\\x00-\\x7F]))*\\x22)))*@(?:(?:(?!.*[^.]{64,})(?:(?:(?:xn--)?[a-z0-9]+(?:-[a-z0-9]+)*\\.){1,126}){1,}(?:(?:[a-z][a-z0-9]*)|(?:(?:xn--)[a-z0-9]+))(?:-[a-z0-9]+)*)|(?:\\[(?:(?:IPv6:(?:(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){7})|(?:(?!(?:.*[a-f0-9][:\\]]){7,})(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){0,5})?::(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){0,5})?)))|(?:(?:IPv6:(?:(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){5}:)|(?:(?!(?:.*[a-f0-9]:){5,})(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){0,3})?::(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){0,3}:)?)))?(?:(?:25[0-5])|(?:2[0-4][0-9])|(?:1[0-9]{2})|(?:[1-9]?[0-9]))(?:\\.(?:(?:25[0-5])|(?:2[0-4][0-9])|(?:1[0-9]{2})|(?:[1-9]?[0-9]))){3}))\\]))/i";
      $raw = $text;      
      $newlines = array("\t","\n","\r","\x20\x20","\0","\x0B");
      $content = str_replace($newlines, "----", html_entity_decode($raw));
      $content2 = preg_replace("/\s/", "-", $content);
      $content2 = preg_replace("/\-+/", "|", $content2);
      $content2 = explode("|", $content2);
      
      $emails = array();
      foreach( $content2 as $line) {
       preg_match("/@/", $line, $match);
       if( count($match) > 0 ) {
        preg_match_all($email_pattern, $line, $email_match);
        if( count($email_match) > 0 ) {
         foreach($email_match[0] as $key=>$email) {
          $emails[] = $email;
         }
        }
       }
      }
      
      return $emails;
     }
?>
```

I try to follow the instructions given on the answers from @jason and it works  now the resulting emails are saved on a CSV file... but the csv file has repeated information and the headers from my index.php are printed as a columns.

Here is my code:

```html
<?php

$show_details     ='no';    // choice : 'yes' or 'no'
$disposable_email    ='no';  // choice : 'yes' or 'no'
$check_mx      ='no';  // choice : 'yes' or 'no'

     
if(!empty($_POST['Check'])){
 if(!empty($_POST['email'])){
 
  $emails = get_email($_POST['email']);
  require_once('emailvalidclass.php'); //include emailvalidclass.php file
  $emailChecker = new emailChecker; // Make a new instance
  if($show_details=='yes'){ $emailChecker->supress_output = 0; }else{ $emailChecker->supress_output = 1; }
  if($disposable_email=='yes'){ $emailChecker->filter_dea = 1; }else{ $emailChecker->filter_dea = 0; }
  if($check_mx=='yes'){ $emailChecker->check_mx = 1; }else{ $emailChecker->check_mx = 0; }
  $emailChecker->smtp_test = 0; 

  $emailsubmited=count($emails);
  
                      
                        
$fileName = 'emails.csv';

header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header("Content-type: text/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename={$fileName}");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Pragma: public");

$fh = @fopen( 'php://output', 'w' );

$headerDisplayed = false;

$array_good_emails=array();
$array_bad_emails=array();   
       
 foreach((array)$emails as $key=>$e){
    
 // Add a header row if it hasn't been added yet
 if(empty($e)) continue;
       
        $e = $emailChecker->check($e);
        $e = $e['result'];
 
        if($e['success']){
         $array_good_emails[]=htmlspecialchars($e['query']);
        }else{
         $array_bad_emails[]=htmlspecialchars($e['query']); 
        }
        
        
    
    // Put the data into the stream
    fputcsv($fh, $array_good_emails);
 }
// Close the file
fclose($fh);
// Make sure nothing else is sent, our file is done
exit;

       
  
     
                            
                            


       }
       
       
      

  

 }else{
 } 



function get_email($text) {
      ## Regex taken from http://bit.ly/Tq2PYP PHP's FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL function.
      $email_pattern = "/(?!(?:(?:\\x22?\\x5C[\\x00-\\x7E]\\x22?)|(?:\\x22?[^\\x5C\\x22]\\x22?)){255,})(?!(?:(?:\\x22?\\x5C[\\x00-\\x7E]\\x22?)|(?:\\x22?[^\\x5C\\x22]\\x22?)){65,}@)(?:(?:[\\x21\\x23-\\x27\\x2A\\x2B\\x2D\\x2F-\\x39\\x3D\\x3F\\x5E-\\x7E]+)|(?:\\x22(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0B\\x0C\\x0E-\\x1F\\x21\\x23-\\x5B\\x5D-\\x7F]|(?:\\x5C[\\x00-\\x7F]))*\\x22))(?:\\.(?:(?:[\\x21\\x23-\\x27\\x2A\\x2B\\x2D\\x2F-\\x39\\x3D\\x3F\\x5E-\\x7E]+)|(?:\\x22(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0B\\x0C\\x0E-\\x1F\\x21\\x23-\\x5B\\x5D-\\x7F]|(?:\\x5C[\\x00-\\x7F]))*\\x22)))*@(?:(?:(?!.*[^.]{64,})(?:(?:(?:xn--)?[a-z0-9]+(?:-[a-z0-9]+)*\\.){1,126}){1,}(?:(?:[a-z][a-z0-9]*)|(?:(?:xn--)[a-z0-9]+))(?:-[a-z0-9]+)*)|(?:\\[(?:(?:IPv6:(?:(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){7})|(?:(?!(?:.*[a-f0-9][:\\]]){7,})(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){0,5})?::(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){0,5})?)))|(?:(?:IPv6:(?:(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){5}:)|(?:(?!(?:.*[a-f0-9]:){5,})(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){0,3})?::(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){0,3}:)?)))?(?:(?:25[0-5])|(?:2[0-4][0-9])|(?:1[0-9]{2})|(?:[1-9]?[0-9]))(?:\\.(?:(?:25[0-5])|(?:2[0-4][0-9])|(?:1[0-9]{2})|(?:[1-9]?[0-9]))){3}))\\]))/i";
      $raw = $text;      
      $newlines = array("\t","\n","\r","\x20\x20","\0","\x0B");
      $content = str_replace($newlines, "----", html_entity_decode($raw));
      $content2 = preg_replace("/\s/", "-", $content);
      $content2 = preg_replace("/\-+/", "|", $content2);
      $content2 = explode("|", $content2);
      
      $emails = array();
      foreach( $content2 as $line) {
       preg_match("/@/", $line, $match);
       if( count($match) > 0 ) {
        preg_match_all($email_pattern, $line, $email_match);
        if( count($email_match) > 0 ) {
         foreach($email_match[0] as $key=>$email) {
          $emails[] = $email;
         }
        }
       }
      }
      
      return $emails;
     }
?>
```

And this is produced csv file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>                           
<!--[if IE 8]> <html lang="en" class="ie8"> <![endif]-->                             
<!--[if IE 9]> <html lang="en" class="ie9"> <![endif]-->                             
<!--[if !IE]><!--> <html lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->                             
<head>                           
    <title>EmailValid</title>                           
    <!-- Meta -->                           
    <meta charset="utf-8">                           
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">                           
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width  initial-scale=1.0">                          
    <meta name="description" content="">                           
    <meta name="author" content="">                               
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">                             
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300 400 300italic 400italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>                        
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400 700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>                           
    <!-- Global CSS -->                           
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">                           
    <!-- Plugins CSS -->                               
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css">                           
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/plugins/prism/prism.css">                           
    <!-- Theme CSS -->                             
    <link id="theme-style" rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/styles.css">                           
    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->                           
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>                           
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>                           
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>                           
    <![endif]-->                           
</head>                            
                           
<body data-spy="scroll">                           
0                           
    <!-- ******PROMO****** -->                           
    <section id="promo" class="promo section offset-header">                           
        <div class="container text-center">                           
            <h2 class="title">Email<span class="highlight">Valid</span></h2>                           
            <p class="intro">Check ZSBox email list validity in real-time                           
   <form method="post">                           
    <textarea rows="10" cols="150" style="color:black" name="email" placeholder="Insert here your text. The robot will extract all the emails from the text"></textarea>                           
    </p>                           
    <div class="btns">                           
     <input type="submit" value="Check" name="Check" class="btn btn-cta-secondary">                           
    </div>                           
   </form>                           
   aksboneyard@sbcglobal.net                           
aksboneyard@sbcglobal.net al__franco@sbcglobal.net                          
aksboneyard@sbcglobal.net al__franco@sbcglobal.net aladydot@aol.com                         
aksboneyard@sbcglobal.net al__franco@sbcglobal.net aladydot@aol.com alabama_annie@yahoo.com                        
aksboneyard@sbcglobal.net al__franco@sbcglobal.net aladydot@aol.com alabama_annie@yahoo.com alac471@yahoo.com                       
aksboneyard@sbcglobal.net al__franco@sbcglobal.net aladydot@aol.com alabama_annie@yahoo.com alac471@yahoo.com akulovvpshark@yahoo.com                      
aksboneyard@sbcglobal.net al__franco@sbcglobal.net aladydot@aol.com alabama_annie@yahoo.com alac471@yahoo.com akulovvpshark@yahoo.com akw408@yahoo.com                     
aksboneyard@sbcglobal.net al__franco@sbcglobal.net aladydot@aol.com alabama_annie@yahoo.com alac471@yahoo.com akulovvpshark@yahoo.com akw408@yahoo.com aksingh@bnr.ca                    
aksboneyard@sbcglobal.net al__franco@sbcglobal.net aladydot@aol.com alabama_annie@yahoo.com alac471@yahoo.com akulovvpshark@yahoo.com akw408@yahoo.com aksingh@bnr.ca aksnownow@mytalk.com                   
aksboneyard@sbcglobal.net al__franco@sbcglobal.net aladydot@aol.com alabama_annie@yahoo.com alac471@yahoo.com akulovvpshark@yahoo.com akw408@yahoo.com aksingh@bnr.ca aksnownow@mytalk.com aktiva@c2i.net                  
aksboneyard@sbcglobal.net al__franco@sbcglobal.net aladydot@aol.com alabama_annie@yahoo.com alac471@yahoo.com akulovvpshark@yahoo.com akw408@yahoo.com aksingh@bnr.ca aksnownow@mytalk.com aktiva@c2i.net alaa_al_saeed@yahoo.com                 
aksboneyard@sbcglobal.net al__franco@sbcglobal.net aladydot@aol.com alabama_annie@yahoo.com alac471@yahoo.com akulovvpshark@yahoo.com akw408@yahoo.com aksingh@bnr.ca aksnownow@mytalk.com aktiva@c2i.net alaa_al_saeed@yahoo.com aks0355@aol.com                
aksboneyard@sbcglobal.net al__franco@sbcglobal.net aladydot@aol.com alabama_annie@yahoo.com alac471@yahoo.com akulovvpshark@yahoo.com akw408@yahoo.com aksingh@bnr.ca aksnownow@mytalk.com aktiva@c2i.net alaa_al_saeed@yahoo.com aks0355@aol.com alabamaalex@yahoo.com               
aksboneyard@sbcglobal.net al__franco@sbcglobal.net aladydot@aol.com alabama_annie@yahoo.com alac471@yahoo.com akulovvpshark@yahoo.com akw408@yahoo.com aksingh@bnr.ca aksnownow@mytalk.com aktiva@c2i.net alaa_al_saeed@yahoo.com aks0355@aol.com alabamaalex@yahoo.com al77blackwolf7@email.com              
aksboneyard@sbcglobal.net al__franco@sbcglobal.net aladydot@aol.com alabama_annie@yahoo.com alac471@yahoo.com akulovvpshark@yahoo.com akw408@yahoo.com aksingh@bnr.ca aksnownow@mytalk.com aktiva@c2i.net alaa_al_saeed@yahoo.com aks0355@aol.com alabamaalex@yahoo.com al77blackwolf7@email.com akula_6@yahoo.com             
aksboneyard@sbcglobal.net al__franco@sbcglobal.net aladydot@aol.com alabama_annie@yahoo.com alac471@yahoo.com akulovvpshark@yahoo.com akw408@yahoo.com aksingh@bnr.ca aksnownow@mytalk.com aktiva@c2i.net alaa_al_saeed@yahoo.com aks0355@aol.com alabamaalex@yahoo.com al77blackwolf7@email.com akula_6@yahoo.com akurt79@yahoo.com            
aksboneyard@sbcglobal.net al__franco@sbcglobal.net aladydot@aol.com alabama_annie@yahoo.com alac471@yahoo.com akulovvpshark@yahoo.com akw408@yahoo.com aksingh@bnr.ca aksnownow@mytalk.com aktiva@c2i.net alaa_al_saeed@yahoo.com aks0355@aol.com alabamaalex@yahoo.com al77blackwolf7@email.com akula_6@yahoo.com akurt79@yahoo.com al81g@hotmail.com           
aksboneyard@sbcglobal.net al__franco@sbcglobal.net aladydot@aol.com alabama_annie@yahoo.com alac471@yahoo.com akulovvpshark@yahoo.com akw408@yahoo.com aksingh@bnr.ca aksnownow@mytalk.com aktiva@c2i.net alaa_al_saeed@yahoo.com aks0355@aol.com alabamaalex@yahoo.com al77blackwolf7@email.com akula_6@yahoo.com akurt79@yahoo.com al81g@hotmail.com alaguvenkat@yahoo.com          
aksboneyard@sbcglobal.net al__franco@sbcglobal.net aladydot@aol.com alabama_annie@yahoo.com alac471@yahoo.com akulovvpshark@yahoo.com akw408@yahoo.com aksingh@bnr.ca aksnownow@mytalk.com aktiva@c2i.net alaa_al_saeed@yahoo.com aks0355@aol.com alabamaalex@yahoo.com al77blackwolf7@email.com akula_6@yahoo.com akurt79@yahoo.com al81g@hotmail.com alaguvenkat@yahoo.com al.jones@aig.com         
aksboneyard@sbcglobal.net al__franco@sbcglobal.net aladydot@aol.com alabama_annie@yahoo.com alac471@yahoo.com akulovvpshark@yahoo.com akw408@yahoo.com aksingh@bnr.ca aksnownow@mytalk.com aktiva@c2i.net alaa_al_saeed@yahoo.com aks0355@aol.com alabamaalex@yahoo.com al77blackwolf7@email.com akula_6@yahoo.com akurt79@yahoo.com al81g@hotmail.com alaguvenkat@yahoo.com al.jones@aig.com alagu6@hotmail.com        
aksboneyard@sbcglobal.net al__franco@sbcglobal.net aladydot@aol.com alabama_annie@yahoo.com alac471@yahoo.com akulovvpshark@yahoo.com akw408@yahoo.com aksingh@bnr.ca aksnownow@mytalk.com aktiva@c2i.net alaa_al_saeed@yahoo.com aks0355@aol.com alabamaalex@yahoo.com al77blackwolf7@email.com akula_6@yahoo.com akurt79@yahoo.com al81g@hotmail.com alaguvenkat@yahoo.com al.jones@aig.com alagu6@hotmail.com
```

Any help on this matter will be much appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: This is not hard to research.

Answer (score 0):

To create a CSV line from an array, use `$csv_line = implode(',',$array_line);`
Spit that out to a file with CSV extension and viola!

Also, could give a more in depth answer if I saw a `print_r()` example of the arrays you are working with(ie if any loops are needed, etc).

Comment: Wow Thank you very much @andrew-coder ! Since I'm very inexpert on PHP I'm trying to understand what you just explain to me... The source code is: ' <?php echo implode("<br>",$array_good_emails); ?> ' <-- create a ' <td> ' for each result ... what you are suggesting is to change that line for ' $csv_line = implode(',',$array_good_emails); ' is that correct? Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably have up the max execution to stop it from timing out.

```
 ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); //300 seconds = 5 minutes
```

This code will generate the csv you'll have to modify it for your needs:

```
<?php
function query_to_csv($db_conn, $query, $filename, $attachment = false, $headers = true) {

    if($attachment) {
        // send response headers to the browser
        header( 'Content-Type: text/csv' );
        header( 'Content-Disposition: attachment;filename='.$filename);
        $fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
    } else {
        $fp = fopen($filename, 'w');
    }

    $result = mysql_query($query, $db_conn) or die( mysql_error( $db_conn ) );

    if($headers) {
        // output header row (if at least one row exists)
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        if($row) {
            fputcsv($fp, array_keys($row));
            // reset pointer back to beginning
            mysql_data_seek($result, 0);
        }
    }

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        fputcsv($fp, $row);
    }

    fclose($fp);
}

// Using the function
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table";
// $db_conn should be a valid db handle

// output as an attachment
query_to_csv($db_conn, $sql, "test.csv", true);

// output to file system
query_to_csv($db_conn, $sql, "test.csv", false);
?>
```

Comment: Thank you @jason-butler !! Really appreciate your help! The script I'm using doesn't use any database since everything it's checked on "real-time" .. Do I need to create a db first so that way I will have the results on a .csv document? Thank you very much.. and sorry for asking...

Comment: No not at all, basically the database results set is an array - the code above can be simplified

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you need:

```
$fileName = 'emails.csv';

header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header("Content-type: text/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename={$fileName}");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Pragma: public");

$fh = @fopen( 'php://output', 'w' );

$headerDisplayed = false;

foreach ( $your_emails_array as $data ) {
    // Add a header row if it hasn't been added yet
    if ( !$headerDisplayed ) {
        // Use the keys from $data as the titles
        fputcsv($fh, array_keys($data));
        $headerDisplayed = true;
    }

    // Put the data into the stream
    fputcsv($fh, $data);
 }
// Close the file
fclose($fh);
// Make sure nothing else is sent, our file is done
exit;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and time @jason-butler I try to use your code on my script, and works but still have problem with the resulting csv.. it  shows every email repeated on every line.I understand you probably don't have so much time to help people.. but I you can help me one more time I will be very thankful.